# Kotlin's new unsigned types not compiling

Tags: kotlin, flutter, unsigned

I'm trying to use the new experimental UByte and UShort Koltin data types, but when trying to compile, there is an `Unresolved reference: UByte` error.

I'm using Kotlin as part of a Flutter plugin package, which targets a native Android app.

Tried to import `koltin.*` explicitly, but nothing works.

**UPDATE:**
This seems to be the Kotlin compiler version that Flutter is using:

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to use them from Dart or from Kotlin?

Comment: I'm trying to use them from Kotlin, but then I send them to Dart. But intermediate results "inside" Kotlin are also of my interest.